# Table causing crash on Apple Watch

Tags: ios, apple-watch

When I try to launch my apple watch app with the following code, it crashes after the log prints "produce" (there is nothing after that). When I remove the code, it does not crash. I cannot figure out what could be going wrong.

```
 NSMutableArray *rowTypesList = himo; //himo is a nsmutablearray that contains info from NSXMLParser
        [_table setRowTypes:rowTypesList];
        for (NSInteger i = 0; i < _table.numberOfRows; i++)
        {
            NSDictionary *itemAtIndex =(NSDictionary *)[himo objectAtIndex:i];
            NSObject *row = [_table rowControllerAtIndex:i];
            Cell *importantRow = (Cell *) row;
            [importantRow.label setText:@"hi"];
        }
NSLog(@"produce");
```

Comment: What is the crash log?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you are mixing your data you want to display in your table with the row controller type.  If you just have a single row controller type of Cell which it appears you do by your code you want the following:

```
[_table setNumberOfRows:[himo count] withRowType:@"theIdentiferYouGaveTheRowControllerInTheStoryboard"];
for (NSInteger i = 0; i < [himo count]; i++) {
    NSDictionary *item = (NSDictionary *)[himo objectAtIndex:i];
    Cell *rowController = [_table rowControllerAtIndex:i];
    [rowController.label setText:@"hi"]; // you probably want to use the data from item here
}
```

Comment: It stopped crashing now thankfully by doing that, but now it is giving me the  error: Error - unable to instantiate row controller class. It also is not changing the text...

Comment: Did you set the class and identifier correctly for your row controller in your storyboard?